# Append my Event handler before existing handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Let's suppose there is an **`<img>`** element that has some `onclick` event handler. For example `onclick` it does `alert("OldEventHandler")`.

**I would like to add my event handler there, before the existing one**.  For example my event handler function does `alert("NewEventHandler")`.

So on click I would like to see "NewEventHandler" popup, and then "OldEventHandler" popup.

This needs to be implemented in pure JavaScript; **no jQuery Please.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can save the original handler, then call it after yours is done:

```
var oldHandler = myElement.onclick;

myElement.onclick = function() {
    // do your stuff here
    ...

    // then call the original
    oldHandler.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: seems not work if add addEventListener handlers additionally to onclick (they would be called first anyway first)

Comment: @alex_1948511 that probably depends on whether the handler added with `addEventListener` is registered as a _capturing_ handler or a _bubbling_ handler.  A `.onclick` handler is treated as the latter, and happens after the capturing handlers.  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this problem would be to create a *generic* event handler that stores an array of functions in some predefined order.  When the `onclick()` event is fired, you can call the functions you need in that order.

Comment: That would work if all handler functions would be set my be. But in this case - default event handler is set by alien code (to which I don't have access), and I don't want to prevent it completely. I just want to insert my handler before it.